# I'm new to Solidity. I'm trying to create a getter function for an array which should return type address, but I'm getting the attached error

Tags: solidity, remix, addresses, arrays, state-variable

```
contract StorageFactory {

    SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray;

    function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
        simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage);
    }

    function get(uint256 _position) public view returns(uint256) {
        return simpleStorageArray(_position);     
    }
}
```

[image]

I know that solidity creates getter functions by default, but I wanna know the code that goes behind.

Answer (score 1):

simpleStorageArray is an array not a function so you want to use square brackets:

```
 simpleStorageArray[_position];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get single entry or full array at one time.

function get(uint256 _position) public view returns(uint256) {

```
    return simpleStorageArray[_position];
```

}

function getFull() public view returns(uint256[] memory _array) {

```
    return simpleStorageArray;
```

}